# how to change in github repository hooks to pre-push

Tags: git, github, gitlab, githooks

I have only access to the git repository, I want to show a message to the user before pushing to the git repo(pre-push). what type of changes I need to do in the hooks folder.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "the git repository".  Do you mean the one on GitHub, or the one on the user's local system?  Also, could you expand on what you mean by "show a message"?  Are you looking to just show a message and let the operation continue, or to prompt the user in some way?  What have you tried to do already?

Comment: @bk2204 on "user's local system", show a message if user is not authorized and operation stop. actually I tried manually but I want to write a script for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a hook in `.git/hooks/pre-push`, which must be executable, which checks if your criteria are met and exits nonzero if not.  If you exit unsuccessfully, then the operation will be aborted.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Some arbitrary criteria.
if [ "$FOO" = bar ]
then
    exit 1
fi
```

Note, however, that hooks are not distributed as part of the repository, so those changes will remain locally and not be pushed.  You can include them in a folder and provide a script to copy them into place, but the user is not obligated to do so and can remove them at any time.

You should also be aware that hooks on the local system can be bypassed without any negative consequences by simply passing `--no-verify` or just by deleting the hook or removing the executable bit, so your goal to show a message that the user is not authorized will not be an effective control.  If you need to restrict access, that must be done on the server.  The [Git FAQ goes into this in more detail](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#restrict-with-hooks).